# do while con sintaxis alternativa

Tags: php

Se puede poner un bucle do while con sintaxis alternativa?

Tengo que mostrar datos de unos artículos, pero antes quiero mostrar la categoría de esos artículos

Si hago lo siguiente

```
<?php while($art = $articulos->fetch_object()): ?>
    <p><?=$art->nombre?></p>
    <p><?=$art->descripcion?></p>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Estaré mostrando el nombre y descripción de los artículos. Pero antes del while quiero mostrar la categoría de los artículos ($art->categoria). Sin embargo hasta que no haga el fetch_object() no tendré disponible la propiedad categoría

Pensé en poner un bucle do while

```
<?php $art = $articulos->fetch->object(); ?>
<p>Categoría: <?=$art->categoria?></p>
<?php do: ?>
    <p><?=$art->nombre?></p>
    <p><?=$art->descripcion?></p>
<?php while($art = $articulos->fetch->object()); ?>
```

Pero me da error y no se dónde poner el endwhile

Se puede hacer una sintaxis alternativa con do while?

Y si no, cómo podría mostrar primero la categoría?. Aprovechando que en la consulta sql ya tengo el nombre de la categoría, para evitar tener que hacer dos consultas, una para mostrar la categoría y otra para mostrar los otros datos

Gracias!

Comment: Es mejor organizar la consulta SQL de modo que los datos vengan anidados. No adaptes el lenguaje a tus necesidades, adapta tus necesidades al lenguaje... A no ser que quieras inventar una nueva lógica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La estructura de do...while en php es muy simple

```
do{
cuarpo del bloque
}while(condición para repetir)
```

En tu ejemplo

```
<?php $art = $articulos->fetch->object(); ?>
<p>Categoría: <?=$art->categoria?></p>
<?php do{ ?>
    <p><?=$art->nombre?></p>
    <p><?=$art->descripcion?></p>
<?php }while($art = $articulos->fetch->object()); ?>
```

El bloque se repite mientras la condición en while() sea cierta. Como mínimo se repite una vez, por tanto este bucle te puede servir.

Answer (score 1):

De la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) de php: PHP ofrece una sintaxis alternativa para algunas de sus estructuras de control, a saber: if, while, for, foreach, y switch. En cada caso, la forma básica de la sintaxis alternativa es cambiar la llave de apertura por dos puntos (:) y la llave de cierre por endif;, endwhile;, endfor;, endforeach;, o endswitch;, respectivamente.

Por ende la respuesta a tu pregunta sería no, no existe la sintaxis alternativa para los bucles do-while.

Otra forma de implementarlo puede ser:

```
<?php
  $art = $articulos->fetch->object();

  echo "<p>Categoría: {$art->categoria}</p>";

  do {
    echo "<p>{$art->nombre}</p>";
    echo "<p>{$art->descripcion}</p>";
  } while($art = $articulos->fetch->object());
?>
```